# What's the correct way to sprintf a float?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to printf/sprintf floats using this code:

```
sprintf(buff, "FPS: %d\n%.4f N %.4f E\nAl: %.1fm Rl: %.1f\n", fps, p_viewer.p.lat, p_viewer.p.lon, p_viewer.p.alt, p_viewer.roll);
```

However I'm getting these warnings when I do so:

```
gfx_game_engine.c:300: warning: format '%.4f' expects type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'float'
gfx_game_engine.c:300: warning: format '%.4f' expects type 'double', but argument 5 has type 'float'
gfx_game_engine.c:300: warning: format '%.1f' expects type 'double', but argument 6 has type 'float'
gfx_game_engine.c:300: warning: format '%.1f' expects type 'double', but argument 7 has type 'float'
```

What's the correct way to sprintf a float? Is there a special format character? I feel that the compiler might be casting the types somehow and this might contribute to it slowing down.

I'm using a dsPIC33FJ128GP802 microcontroller and compiling with MPLAB C30, a variant of GCC v3.23.

Comment: `%f` is float `%lf` double and `%Lf` long double. What compiler are you using?

Comment: If you're concerned about something contributing to slowness, profile it.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be GCC (v3.23) for dsPIC33F. (Also known as Microchip MPLAB C30.)

Comment: @Nathon Small microcontrollers like mine barely have basic debugging features, forget about a profile!

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: According to my sprintf man page from glibc6, `f` and `F` are both for double.

Comment: @Thomas There might be some bug when parsing the dot notation, but seriously, this should work.

Comment: @Thomas: I've had success with PC sampling on small microcontrollers. Particularly if they have JTAG interfaces that don't require the chip to be quiesced. Maybe you can store your fps values in an array to be printed later?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: where do you get your information from. My `man` page and the standard says differently.

Comment: Yeah, sorry only `%f` and `%Lf` are supported by `(s)printf`

Comment: @Nathon These dsPIC33F do have debugging features, but it's limited to two breakpoints and single stepping. You have to allocate one of the onboard timers to check code times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your variant of gcc is broken. In the C language, there is no way to pass a `float` to a variadic function. Default promotions of small types (`char`, `short`, and `float`) up to at least `int`/`double` always apply. I'm guessing whoever hacked gcc for this microcontroller did something to disable promotions, probably with the idea that `double` is slow or hard to pass. You should flame them to hell and back. The correct solution, if a compiler vendor does not want to support `double` correctly, is to make all the floating point types the same size and equivalent to `float`, not to violate the promotion rules of the language.

Another idea: It's also possible that the prototype for `sprintf` is missing or wrong, for instance `int sprintf();` instead of `int sprintf(char *, const char *, ...);`

Comment: I've *always* passed floats on GCC for Linux and never had issues on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, although, I always used GCC >=4, not GCC 3.23.

Comment: @Thomas: When you "pass a `float`" to a variadic function, it's automatically promoted to `double` and passed as double. This behavior is required by the C language.

Comment: Which problem did it end up being? Thanks for accepting my answer but I'm curious. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`float` arguments should automatically be converted to `double`. There seems no other way to print a `float`. Your compiler shouldn't complain in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike for `scanf`, where `%f` means float and `%lf` means double, `printf` does not distinguish between them. So if `printf` (or its variants) are implemented via a library linkage, the compiler will have to convert.